# When does "rebuild from bitcode" showing in iOS archive phase?

Tags: ios

I have an `objective-C` project containing some `Swift` code. Which caused its size to be larger. 
In my other projects when I check the "rebuild from bitcode", the ipa size becomes smaller. but this option is not showing in archive phase of this project.
bitcode enable is NO in build setting

Comment: If you are not enabling bitcode, how do you expect the option to show up?

Comment: @nanibir Thanks but this option is also disabled in other projects.

Comment: Well, i am not sure what to say, how can you rebuild from bitcode, if the said bitcode is...not there?